# Is there a simple SQLAlchemy filter solution for this with subquery instead?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table below

| Dates.day_date | Orders.date_created | Orders.sales | Orders.store_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 | None | None | None |
| 2021-02-02 | 2021-02-02 19:41:17 | 94.8 | 19 |
| 2021-02-03 | None | None | None |
| 2021-02-04 | 2021-02-04 19:21:13 | 24.8 | 8 |
| 2021-02-04 | 2021-02-04 12:11:03 | 4.8 | 10 |
| 2021-02-05 | 2021-02-05 13:44:47 | 44.4 | 8 |

I am trying to filter only one store, but keep all the Dates.

I have tried:

```
.filter(
    or_(
        Orders.id == None,
        Orders.store_id == store.id,
    )
)
```

My issue is that the "Orders.id == None" part of the 'or' filter is looking for all stores where Orders are "None" so when there is another store with an order on that date, the row is filtered out like the first row would be with Orders.store_id == 19 so I end up missing out the 2021-02-02 Date.

| Dates.day_date | Orders.date_created | Orders.sales | Orders.store_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 | None | None | None |
| 2021-02-03 | None | None | None |
| 2021-02-04 | 2021-02-04 19:21:13 | 24.8 | 8 |
| 2021-02-05 | 2021-02-05 13:44:47 | 44.4 | 8 |

I can't figure a way out of this to keep all Days where Orders are "None" for that specific store like Orders.store_id == 8 so it is more like this

| Dates.day_date | Orders.date_created | Orders.sales | Orders.store_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 | None | None | None |
| 2021-02-02 | None | None | None |
| 2021-02-03 | None | None | None |
| 2021-02-04 | 2021-02-04 19:21:13 | 24.8 | 8 |
| 2021-02-05 | 2021-02-05 13:44:47 | 44.4 | 8 |

Is the only way around this to use subquerys?

My current query is:

```
db.session.query(
        Dates.day_date,
        Orders.date_created,
        Orders.sales
    ).select_from(
        Dates
    ).outerjoin(
        Orders, Dates.day_date == cast(Orders.date_created, Date)
    ).filter(or_(
        Orders.store_id == store.id,
        Orders.store_id == None
    )).group_by(
        Orders.date_created,
        Dates.day_date
    ).all()
```

Would I just need a subquery for the first join with Dates and Orders, an d then join it into the query again?

--EDIT--

A pre-filtered subquery seems to have worked

```
orders_day = db.session.query(
                Dates.day_date,
                Orders.id
            ).select_from(
                Dates
            ).outerjoin(
                Orders, Dates.day_date == cast(Orders.date_created, Date)
            ).filter(
                Orders.store_id == store.id
            ).group_by(
                Orders.id,
                Dates.day_date
            ).order_by(
                Dates.day_date
            ).subquery()
```

I then added this to the original query:

```
query = db.session.query(
            Dates.day_date,
            Orders.date_created,
            Orders.sales,
            Orders.store_id
        ).select_from(
            Dates
        ).outerjoin(
            orders_day, Dates.day_date == orders_day.c.day_date,
        ).outerjoin(
            Orders, orders_day.c.id == Orders.id
        ).group_by(
            Dates.day_date,
            Orders.date_created,
            Orders.sales,
            Orders.store_id
        ).all()
```

Comment: The way you've worded this isn't super obvious, but on a quick glance it looks like switching `or_` to `and_` would work?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Peter, but the and_ filter seems to give me no results at all.   I'm having trouble figuring it out in my own head to even write an explanation for it.

Comment: Try write out exactly what you expect to happen. I'm not an expert so might not be of much help, but honestly I don't have a clue what you're trying to do there lol.

Comment: You're right, it didn't actually make sense when I re-read it, but I have edited it now so hopefully it will make more sense

Comment: Perhaps your issue is not having `Orders.store_id` in `group_by`?